# Multiple container next to each other in Bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap layout which I am trying to develop as a dashboard.
I have a `container-fluid` like this

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
</div>
```

It;s height is `100vh` and width `250px`. I have applied a `margin-left:-240px` so that it hides and when the user hovers over the 10px div the whole div shows up using `transitions`.

My problem is to place a main div next to it,like so

[image]

How can I achieve this? Should I add another `container` or `row`?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) can help you.

Comment: Do you want the content next to the _sidebar_ that you're hide/showing to slide in and out with the sidebar? Or is it supposed to overlap the content?

Comment: @this.Believer - You have several good comments and suggestions here. Have you tried them? You need to clarify the question so that we can help.

Comment: I need it to slide in/out not overlap them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want the sidebar to push the content to its right over when it opens or if you want the sidebar to overlay the content when it opens.

Here is a solution for an overlaid sidebar.

```js
$( '.sidebar' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
  $( this ).toggleClass( 'closed' );
} );
```

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  transition: left 500ms ease-in-out;
  z-index: 5;
}
.sidebar.closed {
  left: -240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="sidebar closed">
  <p>
    Sidebar
  </p>
</aside>
<div class="container-fluid">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      .col-md-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      .col-md-6
    </div>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: I want the sidebar to push content to right not overlay.

Comment: @this.Believer you need to specify that in your question.

Comment: okay sorry about that. Can you please tell me how I can do that?

Comment: you have marked duplicate in one and commenting in one. I am confused. @ZimSystem

Comment: @this.Believer I don't see anything being marked as _"duplicate."_ Not sure what you're getting at. You currently have two answers, **1)** an overlay (by me) and **2)** a slide over (by ZimSystem) solution. If these solutions don't work for you **please** update your answer with more specifics and a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: as I said your solution works for me except for one case that the sidebar push the content to the right not overlap the content. @hungerstar

Comment: @this.Believer yes, I understand this. My last comment was in reference to a comment you made to ZimSystem and asking you to clarify your _"marked duplicate"_ statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can you the new auto-layout `col` class..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar bg-faded">Sidebar</div>
        <div class="col bg-inverse text-white">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/pDFygIAy9G

Comment: I don't really understand what is happening. Could you please explain the `p-2` class which you have used in the demo. I suppose it is flexbox classes?

Comment: It's just padding. You shoud [read the docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/). Accept an answer so others know the question is resolved.